# Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Phone missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm currently developing an windows universal app. I'm using sqlite, which works fine for the Windows 8.1 Project, but fails for the Windows Phone Project ("sqlite3.dll not found"). I think it has something to do with the missing SDK reference to "Microsoft Visual c++ 2013 Runtime Package for Windows Phone".

There is no opton for this SDK, when trying to add it over:
Add reference -> Windows Phone 8.1 -> Extensions

I tried to repair visual studio 2015 community and install "Microsoft Visual c++ 2013 Redistributable" but the problem still persists

**EDIT:**

After updating my OS to Win10 and reinstalling VisualStudio 2015 (which both haven't resolved my problem), I finally was able to fix it:

I just copied the missing SDK directories from another developer machine to my machine. After that, it worked but I have still no clue about the underlying problem...

Answer (score 0):

I've faced with the absolutely same issue: "sqlite3.dll not found" and no option to add reference to "microsoft visual c++ 2013 runtime package for windows phone".
I was able to resolved that by uninstalling visual studio 2013 (which was also installed on that PC)

Comment: i installed Windows App Certification Kit 3.3 for Windows 8.1 and this problem got resolved. you can download it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt637082(v=vs.85).aspx